# Uniformly convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x^n)}{(x^n+n^x)} $

Tags: real-analysis

I have found the pointwise convergence in the interval $[0,1)$ and $(1,+\infty)$ but for uniform convergence how can I use Weierstrass theorem?

Can I prove $\sup|S_N(x)-S(x)|\rightarrow 0$ in those interval?
For $x \in [0,1):  |S_N(x)-S(x)|\le \sum_{n=N+1}^{+\infty} \frac{x^n}{x^n+n^x}$